# Pydev remote debugging "No Module"

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm working with eclipse pydev-plugin for my python development. I got the remote debugger working and can also run my python script.

However, i cannot run the debugger with my remote modules:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
```

Did i miss something?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import RPi.* as GPIO
```

And check whether you are able to import the library or not.If not do following steps for linux:

````
sudo apt-get install rpi.gpio
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/R/RPi.GPIO/RPi.GPIO-0.5.11.tar.gz
cd RPi.GPIO-0.5.11
sudo python setup.py install
cd ~
sudo rm -rf RPi.GPIO-0.*
```
For more information: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/05/install-rpi-gpio-python-library/
````

Comment: As i've written above, my script works on the raspberry. I cannot debug remote.